# Twilio REST + Rails task without waiting for a response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, rest, twilio

I have a rake task that on a cron job sends out a bulk of the messages via Twilio (using their Twilio REST client):

```
def self.twilio_client
    Twilio::REST::Client.new(ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_ID'], ENV['TWILIO_TOKEN'])
end

scheduled_messages.each do |scheduled_message|
    MessagesSender.twilio_client.messages.create(
        :to => scheduled_message.phone_number,
        :messaging_service_sid => ENV['TWILIO_MSID'],
        :body => scheduled_message.body
    )
end
```

It works totally fine. However, my task waits for each response from Twilio and is not progressing to the next one until previous is finished. As I use Twilio's messaging service, I think I'm not utilising simultaneous sendout using my multiple numbers. As a result, when I have to send 10000 messages, it takes a very very long time to send them all out.

How can I speed up the process? Is it possible at all not to wait for the response? Do I need to do it in threads to utilise the messaging service?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You are being rate limited, even if you're using multiple numbers to send the messages using the messaging service. When you've got that many messages to send its always going to take a long time.

I recommend setting up a background job to process all the messages. That has a couple of benefits: you'd be able to tweak the number of workers you use to get the best possible performance and if a message fails in the middle, the remaining batch of messages will still be sent (which isn't the case with your current code).

I wrote a blog post a while back on how to set up [Rails' ActiveJob for sending messages in the background](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/10/delay-api-calls-to-twilio-with-rails-active-job-and-sidekiq.html). You could also use a gem like [Textris](https://github.com/visualitypl/textris) which handles that for you too.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are rate limited based on the plan that you have with Twilio.
https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/how-many-calls-and-sms-messages-per-second-can-my-twilio-account-make?baseUrl=%2Fhelp%2F

Your best bet is to setup delayed processing like delayed job and then just delay each send so that it is processed by your queue.